# Extracting URLs from a String that do not contain 'http'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following 3 strings...

```
a = "The URL is www.google.com"
b = "The URL is google.com"
c = "The URL is http://www.google.com"
```

Ruby's URI extract method only returns the URL in the third string, because it contains the http part.

```
URI.extract(a)
=> []

URI.extract(b)
=> []

URI.extract(c)
=> ["http://www.google.com"]
```

How can I create a method to detect and return the URL in all 3 instances?

Comment: got new privilege "down vote"?

Comment: I dont know who is doing the downvoting, but it isnt me! I am appreciative of all answers. Though none of the downvoted answers I can see so far will return the url in strings a and b.

Comment: @TBenedyk Are you sure?

Comment: @sawa whilst your answer does return what I want in this specific instance. It is not what I was really after. At the moment Sucrenoir's answer looks most promising. I will mark as correct when responses have stopped coming in and I have a chance to properly try them all :)

Comment: @TBenedyk You have to be more specific about what counts as a URL. The difficult part is your string `b`. How is the URL supposed to be identified in that string? Sucrenoir's answer identifies it by assuming that a URL includes at least one period. If that is what you want, you should define so in the question. And that means that the parts other than the URL in your strings do not include any period. Is that the case?

Comment: @TBenedyk check now.. probably I made what you were looking for.

Comment: I have not accepted any answer yet because I intend to test them all properly until I find the best solution. Though just to confirm, simply pulling out the last word in the string because that is where I have put the URLs in this example is not what I was looking for. It needs to be able to detect them anywhere within the string. Thank you @sawa for highlighting the issue with Sucrenoir's in instances with a preceeding period and Thank you Priti, I will take a look.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use regular expressions :

Here is a basic one that should work for most cases :

```
/(https?:\/\/)?\w*\.\w+(\.\w+)*(\/\w+)*(\.\w*)?/.match( a ).to_s
```

This will only fetch the first url in the string and return a string.

Comment: if it is possible that there are more than one url in the string you can use 'scan' on his expressing like this: mystring.scan(REG_EXPR).each do |match|

Comment: This will not fetch the query params of the url

Answer (score 9):

There's no perfect solution to this problem: it's fraught with edge cases. However, you might be able to get tolerably good results using something like the [regular expressions used by Twitter to extract URLs from tweets](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/rb/lib/twitter-text/regex.rb) (stripping off the extra leading spaces is left as an exercise!):

```
require './regex.rb'

def extract_url(s)
  s[Twitter::Regex[:valid_url]]
end

a = "The URL is www.google.com"
b = "The URL is google.com"
c = "The URL is http://www.google.com"

extract_url(a)
# => " www.google.com"
extract_url(b)
# => " google.com"
extract_url(c)
# => " http://www.google.com"
```

Comment: @threedaymonnk Well I just learned a new way, that is pretty cool

Comment: Thanks @threedaymonnk, this was really helpful, though a little overkill for my needs in this instance. I'm sure I'll find use for this in the future so I've given an upvote :)

Comment: Please, note that mentioned repo is not existing any more, please use a new one https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/rb/lib/twitter-text/regex.rb

Comment: looks nice but link to the code is currently not available

Comment: they changed the classes so now it should be-`Twitter::TwitterText::Regex[:valid_url]`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be satisfied with Sucrenoir's answer. The essence of Sucrenoir's answer is to identity a URL by assuming that it includes at least one period. if that is the case, Sucrenoir's regex can be simplified (not equivalently, but for the most part) to this:

```
string[/\S+\.\S+/]
```

Comment: please withdraw down-vote who did such work. I think all the answers are correct here.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I used a while ago, hopefully it helps

```
validates :url, :format =>
        { :with => URI::regexp(%w(http https)), :message => "Not Valid URL" }
```

Pass it through that validation (I assume your using a database)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this method. Hope it will work for you

```
def get_url(str)
    arr = str.split(' ')
    url = nil
    arr.map {|arr_str| url = arr_str if arr_str.include?('.com')}
    url
  end
```

This is your example

```
get_url("The URL is www.google.com") #=> www.google.com
get_url("The URL is google.com") #=> google.com
get_url("The URL is http://www.google.com") #=> http://www.google.com
```

Comment: what about .edu, .org, etc?

Comment: @Tall Paul, yes.. need to think for those also .